# On Production server laravel project giving (1/1) TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

On Production server laravel project giving error on authentication

```
(1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)
```

This project is working perfectly on localhost and I checked on my private server too its working.

**I have checked all the possible bugs like**

1. Permissions to storage folder. also checked session file all are same as required.
2. checked csrf_tokens methods as well

Finally I checked what's status of auth session and toke key. may be this error due to mismatch these. but why it is on this server? this is quite a strange issue.

after checking my session key and token key both are different.

what should I do next to fixed this problem. Is any problem with my godaddy server?

please help me if anybody experienced this issue.

Comment: You csrf token managed by database table or?

Comment: @Krishna Gupta , Im also receiving same error on my Godaddy server, did you find any solution for this ?